# Filtering a list of tuples to contain max and min

Tags: python

I have generated a long list of tuples (format below). Each tuple in the list has time as the first element and an event as the third member. The second member is always the same and identify the list from other similar lists that I will have to deal with. The tuples have many different third element and each have multiple entries at different values of time which is the first element.

I am trying to filter the list to delete all but the min and max value of time (first item in tuple) for each event (third member of tuple). I tried using list comprehension but quickly got confused.

```
('1.3433', 'VOLTAGE DEVIATION', 'DNLP2G23.575')
('1.3433', 'VOLTAGE DEVIATION', 'DNLP2G23.575')
('1.3433', 'VOLTAGE DEVIATION', 'DNLP2G23.575')
('1.3433', 'VOLTAGE DEVIATION', 'DNLP2G23.575')
('1.3433', 'VOLTAGE DEVIATION', 'DNLP2G23.575')
('1.3433', 'VOLTAGE DEVIATION', 'DNLP2G23.575')
('1.3433', 'VOLTAGE DEVIATION', 'DNLP2G23.575')
('1.3433', 'VOLTAGE DEVIATION', 'DNLP2G23.575')
('1.3433', 'VOLTAGE DEVIATION', 'DNLP2G23.575')
('1.3467', 'VOLTAGE DEVIATION', 'DNLP2G23.575')
('1.3467', 'VOLTAGE DEVIATION', 'DNLP2G23.575')
('1.3467', 'VOLTAGE DEVIATION', 'DNLP2G23.575')
('1.3467', 'VOLTAGE DEVIATION', 'DNLP1_G1.575')
('1.3467', 'VOLTAGE DEVIATION', 'DNLP1_G1.575')
('1.3467', 'VOLTAGE DEVIATION', 'DNLP1_G1.575')
('1.3467', 'VOLTAGE DEVIATION', 'DNLP1_G1.575')
('1.3533', 'VOLTAGE DEVIATION', 'DIFICULT 230')
('1.3533', 'VOLTAGE DEVIATION', 'DIFICULT 230')
('1.3533', 'VOLTAGE DEVIATION', 'DIFICULT 230')
('1.3533', 'VOLTAGE DEVIATION', 'DIFICULT 230')
('1.3533', 'VOLTAGE DEVIATION', 'DIFICULT 230')
('1.3533', 'VOLTAGE DEVIATION', 'DIFICULT 230')
('1.3533', 'VOLTAGE DEVIATION', 'DIFICULT 230')
('1.3533', 'VOLTAGE DEVIATION', 'DIFICULT 230')
('1.3533', 'VOLTAGE DEVIATION', 'DIFICULT 230')
('1.3567', 'VOLTAGE DEVIATION', 'DIFICULT 230')
('1.3600', 'VOLTAGE DEVIATION', 'DIFICULT 230')
('1.3600', 'VOLTAGE DEVIATION', '7MIHL G1.575')
('1.3600', 'VOLTAGE DEVIATION', '7MIHL G1.575')
('1.3600', 'VOLTAGE DEVIATION', '7MIHL G1.575')
('1.3600', 'VOLTAGE DEVIATION', '7MIHL G1.575')
('1.3600', 'VOLTAGE DEVIATION', '7MIHL G1.575')
('1.3600', 'VOLTAGE DEVIATION', '7MIHL G1.575')
('1.3600', 'VOLTAGE DEVIATION', '7MIHL G1.575')
('1.3600', 'VOLTAGE DEVIATION', '7MIHL G1.575')
('1.3600', 'VOLTAGE DEVIATION', '7MIHL G1.575')
('1.3600', 'VOLTAGE DEVIATION', '7MIHL G1.575')
('1.3800', 'VOLTAGE DEVIATION', '7MIHL G1.575')
('1.3800', 'VOLTAGE DEVIATION', '7MIHL G1.575')
('1.3800', 'VOLTAGE DEVIATION', 'HORIZ_G .575')
('1.3800', 'VOLTAGE DEVIATION', 'MEDBOWCO 115')
('1.3800', 'VOLTAGE DEVIATION', 'MEDBOWCO 115')
('1.3800', 'VOLTAGE DEVIATION', 'STNDPSVC 230')
('1.3800', 'VOLTAGE DEVIATION', 'STNDPSVC 230')
('1.3800', 'VOLTAGE DEVIATION', 'STNDPSVC 230')
('1.3800', 'VOLTAGE DEVIATION', 'STNDPSVC 230')
('1.3800', 'VOLTAGE DEVIATION', 'STNDPSVC 230')
('1.3800', 'VOLTAGE DEVIATION', 'STNDPSVC 230')
('1.3867', 'VOLTAGE DEVIATION', 'MINERS  34.5')
('1.3867', 'VOLTAGE DEVIATION', 'MINERS  34.5')
('1.3867', 'VOLTAGE DEVIATION', 'MINERS  34.5')
('1.3867', 'VOLTAGE DEVIATION', 'MINERS  34.5')
('1.3867', 'VOLTAGE DEVIATION', 'MINERS  34.5')
('1.3867', 'VOLTAGE DEVIATION', 'MINERS  34.5')
('1.3867', 'VOLTAGE DEVIATION', 'MINERS  34.5')
('1.3867', 'VOLTAGE DEVIATION', 'MINERS  34.5')
('1.3867', 'VOLTAGE DEVIATION', 'MINERS  34.5')
('1.3867', 'VOLTAGE DEVIATION', 'MINERS  34.5')
('1.3867', 'VOLTAGE DEVIATION', 'MINERS  34.5')
('1.3900', 'VOLTAGE DEVIATION', 'MINERS  34.5')
('1.3900', 'VOLTAGE DEVIATION', 'MINERS  34.5')
('1.3900', 'VOLTAGE DEVIATION', 'MINERS  34.5')
('1.3900', 'VOLTAGE DEVIATION', 'MINERS  34.5')
('1.3900', 'VOLTAGE DEVIATION', 'MINERS  34.5')
('1.3900', 'VOLTAGE DEVIATION', 'MINERS  34.5')
('1.3900', 'VOLTAGE DEVIATION', 'MINERS  34.5')
('1.3900', 'VOLTAGE DEVIATION', 'MINERS  34.5')
('1.3900', 'VOLTAGE DEVIATION', 'MINERS  34.5')
'1.4233', 'VOLTAGE DEVIATION', 'FT CRK2 34.5')
('1.4233', 'VOLTAGE DEVIATION', 'FT CRK2 34.5')
('1.4233', 'VOLTAGE DEVIATION', 'FT CRK2 34.5')
('1.4233', 'VOLTAGE DEVIATION', 'FT CRK2 34.5')
('1.4233', 'VOLTAGE DEVIATION', 'FT CRK2 34.5')
('1.4233', 'VOLTAGE DEVIATION', 'FT CRK2 34.5')
('1.4233', 'VOLTAGE DEVIATION', 'FT CRK2 34.5')
('1.4233', 'VOLTAGE DEVIATION', 'FT CRK2 34.5')
('1.4233', 'VOLTAGE DEVIATION', 'FT CRK2 34.5')
('1.4233', 'VOLTAGE DEVIATION', 'FT CRK2 34.5')
('1.4233', 'VOLTAGE DEVIATION', 'FT CRK2 34.5')
('1.4267', 'VOLTAGE DEVIATION', 'FT CRK2 34.5')
('1.4267', 'VOLTAGE DEVIATION', 'FT CRK2 34.5')
('1.4267', 'VOLTAGE DEVIATION', 'FT CRK2 34.5')
('1.4267', 'VOLTAGE DEVIATION', 'FT CRK2 34.5')
('1.4267', 'VOLTAGE DEVIATION', 'FT CRK2 34.5')
('1.4800', 'VOLTAGE DEVIATION', 'HIPLN_G .575')
('1.4800', 'VOLTAGE DEVIATION', 'HIPLN_G .575')
('1.4800', 'VOLTAGE DEVIATION', 'HIPLN_G .575')
('1.4800', 'VOLTAGE DEVIATION', 'HIPLN_G .575')
('1.4800', 'VOLTAGE DEVIATION', 'HIPLN_G .575')
('1.4800', 'VOLTAGE DEVIATION', 'HIPLN_G .575')
('1.4800', 'VOLTAGE DEVIATION', 'HIPLN_G .575')
('1.4800', 'VOLTAGE DEVIATION', 'HIPLN_G .575')
('1.4800', 'VOLTAGE DEVIATION', 'HIPLN_G .575')
('1.4833', 'VOLTAGE DEVIATION', 'HIPLN_G .575')
('1.4833', 'VOLTAGE DEVIATION', 'HIPLN_G .575')
('1.4833', 'VOLTAGE DEVIATION', 'HIPLN_G .575')
('1.4833', 'VOLTAGE DEVIATION', 'HIPLN_G .575')
('1.4833', 'VOLTAGE DEVIATION', 'HIPLN_G .575')
```

Result after filter is

```
('1.3433', 'VOLTAGE DEVIATION', 'DNLP2G23.575')
('1.3467', 'VOLTAGE DEVIATION', 'DNLP2G23.575')
('1.3467', 'VOLTAGE DEVIATION', 'DNLP1_G1.575')
('1.3467', 'VOLTAGE DEVIATION', 'DNLP1_G1.575')
('1.3533', 'VOLTAGE DEVIATION', 'DIFICULT 230')
('1.3600', 'VOLTAGE DEVIATION', 'DIFICULT 230')
('1.3600', 'VOLTAGE DEVIATION', '7MIHL G1.575')
('1.3800', 'VOLTAGE DEVIATION', '7MIHL G1.575')
('1.3800', 'VOLTAGE DEVIATION', 'HORIZ_G .575')
('1.3800', 'VOLTAGE DEVIATION', 'MEDBOWCO 115')
('1.3800', 'VOLTAGE DEVIATION', 'MEDBOWCO 115')
('1.3800', 'VOLTAGE DEVIATION', 'STNDPSVC 230')
('1.3800', 'VOLTAGE DEVIATION', 'STNDPSVC 230')
('1.3800', 'VOLTAGE DEVIATION', 'STNDPSVC 230')
('1.3867', 'VOLTAGE DEVIATION', 'MINERS  34.5')
('1.3900', 'VOLTAGE DEVIATION', 'MINERS  34.5')
'1.4233', 'VOLTAGE DEVIATION', 'FT CRK2 34.5')
('1.4267', 'VOLTAGE DEVIATION', 'FT CRK2 34.5')
('1.4800', 'VOLTAGE DEVIATION', 'HIPLN_G .575')
('1.4833', 'VOLTAGE DEVIATION', 'HIPLN_G .575')`
```

I am trying the code below but I am getting an error. I am fairly new to this so please tell me if I am doing something incorrect. m1 in the code is my list of tuples generated from the findall. I have imported ast at the top of my code.

```
       m1 = re.findall(pattern1,wholefile)
       m1=[ast.literal_eval(t) for t in m1] 
       m1=[(float(a),b,c) for a,b,c in m1] 
       keys=sorted({t[2] for t in m1}) 
       for key in keys: 
           group=filter(lambda t: t[2]==key,m1)
           print '{}:\n\tmax: {}\n\tmin: {}'.format(key,max(group),min(group))
```

Comment: What errors are you getting? Perhaps it is the missing opening parenthesis before '1.4233'

Comment: I ran this again using Python 2.7 with no problems. Previously I was running Python 2.5 and was having other problems with the Pywin32 module. Is there any reason that this would be a problem in Python 2.5?

Comment: One more question. If I want to assign the max and min times to variables (say t1max and t1min) so that I can calculate the duration (t1max-t1min), would that be t1max = max(group) within the for loop?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This works (as long as you really have a list of tuples with the first value a float):

```
keys=sorted({t[2] for t in tups})
for key in keys:
    group=filter(lambda t: t[2]==key,tups)
    print '{}:\n\tmax: {}\n\tmin: {}'.format(key,max(group),min(group))
```

Prints:

```
MIHL G1.575:
    max: (1.38, 'VOLTAGE DEVIATION', '7MIHL G1.575')
    min: (1.36, 'VOLTAGE DEVIATION', '7MIHL G1.575')
DIFICULT 230:
    max: (1.36, 'VOLTAGE DEVIATION', 'DIFICULT 230')
    min: (1.3533, 'VOLTAGE DEVIATION', 'DIFICULT 230')
DNLP1_G1.575:
    max: (1.3467, 'VOLTAGE DEVIATION', 'DNLP1_G1.575')
    min: (1.3467, 'VOLTAGE DEVIATION', 'DNLP1_G1.575')
DNLP2G23.575:
    max: (1.3467, 'VOLTAGE DEVIATION', 'DNLP2G23.575')
    min: (1.3433, 'VOLTAGE DEVIATION', 'DNLP2G23.575')
FT CRK2 34.5:
    max: (1.4267, 'VOLTAGE DEVIATION', 'FT CRK2 34.5')
    min: (1.4233, 'VOLTAGE DEVIATION', 'FT CRK2 34.5')
HIPLN_G .575:
    max: (1.4833, 'VOLTAGE DEVIATION', 'HIPLN_G .575')
    min: (1.48, 'VOLTAGE DEVIATION', 'HIPLN_G .575')
HORIZ_G .575:
    max: (1.38, 'VOLTAGE DEVIATION', 'HORIZ_G .575')
    min: (1.38, 'VOLTAGE DEVIATION', 'HORIZ_G .575')
MEDBOWCO 115:
    max: (1.38, 'VOLTAGE DEVIATION', 'MEDBOWCO 115')
    min: (1.38, 'VOLTAGE DEVIATION', 'MEDBOWCO 115')
MINERS  34.5:
    max: (1.39, 'VOLTAGE DEVIATION', 'MINERS  34.5')
    min: (1.3867, 'VOLTAGE DEVIATION', 'MINERS  34.5')
STNDPSVC 230:
    max: (1.38, 'VOLTAGE DEVIATION', 'STNDPSVC 230')
    min: (1.38, 'VOLTAGE DEVIATION', 'STNDPSVC 230')
```

---

Based on your comment, sounds you do have text that LOOKS like tuples. Therefore, to convert that to actual tuples:

```
import ast

tups=[ast.literal_eval(t) for t in tups]
tups=[(float(a),b,c) for a,b,c in tups]
```

Comment: ast? Reading it using `csv` would have been much better and avoid unnecessary eval.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid: You would still need to deal with the parens with CSV... I removed the part because I was mainly just dealing with the formatting of the question and it was not clear that he actually had tuples...

Comment: The list of tuples were the result of a findall with three groups. I assigned the result of the findall to my list of tuples. Thanks for this, I will try them all to see which works best for me.

Comment: To use this solution would I first have to loop through the list and convert all the first tuple values to float?

Comment: @user1642486: You will need to do that with ANY of the solutions. Otherwise you will get lexigraphic min / max: `max('2','15')` produces '2' if you do not convert to floats.

Answer (score 4):

Refactoring your tuples into a dict makes life easier.

```
from collections import defaultdict

d = defaultdict(list)
for t,_,v in your_tuple_list:
     d[v].append(t)
```

After that, `d` has a key for each event, and a list of associated times for that time period.

It will look like this (sort of):

```
>>> d['DNLP2G23.575']
['1.3433'....]
```

Now the problem becomes finding the min and max of each list; and that is easy with `min()` and `max()`

Once you run through that, you'll have the data set in the order you want; and you can convert it back to a tuple/list/etc.

If you are keen you can convert the list to a `set` which will eliminate duplicate times and save you some time by speeding up the min/max; assuming its a large list of tuples you have to calculate.

You should also cast your times to `float` - and you can do that in the main loop: `d[v].append(float(t))`. This is to make sure the max and min work correctly.

Answer (score 3):

Using [itertools.groupby](http://docs.python.org/library/itertools.html#itertools.groupby) for this:

```
>>> import itertools
>>> import operator
>>> results = []
>>> for key, group in itertools.groupby(tuplelist, operator.itemgetter(2)):
...    group = list(group)
...    results.append(min(group))
...    results.append(max(group))
...
>>> pprint.pprint(results)
[('1.3433', 'VOLTAGE DEVIATION', 'DNLP2G23.575'),
 ('1.3467', 'VOLTAGE DEVIATION', 'DNLP2G23.575'),
 ('1.3467', 'VOLTAGE DEVIATION', 'DNLP1_G1.575'),
 ('1.3467', 'VOLTAGE DEVIATION', 'DNLP1_G1.575'),
 ('1.3533', 'VOLTAGE DEVIATION', 'DIFICULT 230'),
 ('1.3600', 'VOLTAGE DEVIATION', 'DIFICULT 230'),
 ('1.3600', 'VOLTAGE DEVIATION', '7MIHL G1.575'),
 ('1.3800', 'VOLTAGE DEVIATION', '7MIHL G1.575'),
 ('1.3800', 'VOLTAGE DEVIATION', 'HORIZ_G .575'),
 ('1.3800', 'VOLTAGE DEVIATION', 'HORIZ_G .575'),
 ('1.3800', 'VOLTAGE DEVIATION', 'MEDBOWCO 115'),
 ('1.3800', 'VOLTAGE DEVIATION', 'MEDBOWCO 115'),
 ('1.3800', 'VOLTAGE DEVIATION', 'STNDPSVC 230'),
 ('1.3800', 'VOLTAGE DEVIATION', 'STNDPSVC 230'),
 ('1.3867', 'VOLTAGE DEVIATION', 'MINERS  34.5'),
 ('1.3900', 'VOLTAGE DEVIATION', 'MINERS  34.5'),
 ('1.4233', 'VOLTAGE DEVIATION', 'FT CRK2 34.5'),
 ('1.4267', 'VOLTAGE DEVIATION', 'FT CRK2 34.5'),
 ('1.4800', 'VOLTAGE DEVIATION', 'HIPLN_G .575'),
 ('1.4833', 'VOLTAGE DEVIATION', 'HIPLN_G .575')]
```

Notes:

1. The min/max is done on the elements of the tuple, in order. However, the first element is actually a string not a float, so you might need to pass the `key` argument to min and max to get it to use a different value
2. This will only work if all of the same values for the grouped key are together in the list. In your sample output, this was the case, but if not, you might have to sort the list first.

Comment: +1 too (although you need to `float`ify before taking the max and the min.) The only caveat I can think of is that this requires the keyed elements to be contiguous, whereas the `defaultdict` approach doesn't.  You could sort to get around that.

Comment: All the same values are always together because they represent linear time. The time step is much smaller than these numbers so they look like repeats but they are all different. The analysis was done with a much smaller granularity but my reports will use the printed granularity.

Answer (score 0):

This may be overkill if you only have a handful of tuples, but if you have a long list of and are able to use external libraries, then take a look at [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org). Assuming that your variable containing the tuples is `tuplelist` then the following gives the output you want:

```
import pandas
df = pandas.DataFrame.from_records(tuplelist)
df = pandas.concat([df.groupby([1, 2]).min(), 
                df.groupby([1, 2]).max() ])
df = df.sort().reset_index().reindex(columns = [0,1,2])
print list(tuple(x) for x in df.values)
```

Comment: This looks interesting but I am not sure I would be able to use external libraries. I will find out. Thanks!